# Why oil, gas and metal ETFs simultanously drop?

Tags: investing, etf

As an ETF beginner I have four ETFs like

1. iShares Oil & Gas Exploration & Production UCITS ETF - USD ACC Morningstar Rating Morningstar Rating™ , **WKN**: A1JKQL, Oil & Gas Exploration & Production Index
2. BNP Paribas Easy Energy & Metals Enhanced Roll UCITS ETF - EUR ACC, **WKN**: A2AE6P
3. Lyxor Bloomberg Equal-weight Commodity ex-Agriculture UCITS ETF - I USD DIS, **WKN**: ETF090, 12 commodities in energy, noble and industry metals
4. Lyxor Commodities Refinitiv/CoreCommodity CRB TR UCITS ETF - EUR ACC, **WKN**: LYX0Z2, energy, metals and agricultural products

**All of them drop in the last 14 days**. These drops are something not usual for these ETFs, their historic performance is not affected by drop in this amount.

**Q1**: Does somebody understand what happens with these ETFs?

**Q2**: And, much more interessant question for me: which investigation ways do you use to understand such trends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The world is being rocked by a global health issue, even if the danger has passed in many parts of the world, the world economy is still being impacted.

Inflation is at historic highs in many parts of the world, because of the health crisis and the financial things done to fight the health crisis.

The US just bumped up their interest rates.

Europe and other areas of the world are being impacted by the invasion of Ukraine. This is impacting Oil/Gas, and Agriculture.

With all these unknowns many industries are trying to predict the impact on their markets. For example if inflation and interest rates are a problem, then consumers will not buy cars next year even if the chip shortage goes away...

Answer (score 1):

Do they have similar holdings? I find that energy and oil stocks drop because fear of recession that could lead to their decrease use and decreased demand. Maybe same for metals too?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).